# R plot() returns 'compressed' series

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot thwo data series and a common date (`POSIXct`) on a chart for a personal project that I'm developing. I've firstly used `plot()` to generate the chart and the main data line, applying `axis.date()` to visualize the dates on the chart. Then, I've used `lines()` to plot the other data series but, as a result, a very strange behaviour happens: all the series on the chart appear to be 'compressed' and no date is shown:
[image]

This is how the chart should look like whitout dates:

[image]

This is the code I've written to generate the first chart:

```
plot(x=df$Data[start:end],
     y=df$Losses[start:end],
     xaxt="n",
     type='l', 
     ylim=c(-0.5,0.5),
     xlab='Dates',
     ylab='Losses/VaR')
axis.POSIXct(1,at=seq(as.Date(df$Data[start]),as.Date(df$Data[end]),by="1 day"),format="%m/%Y")
lines(df$VaRevt[start:end], col='red', x=df$Data[start:end])
```

I really can't figure out what's wrong...
Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks!

I post here a sample of my data (start=1, end=201):
[file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/c6b410970a3b7e739ddfbe89285b764820201013180947/f53a26)

I've found that I've stored `df$Data` as `POSIXct` without specifying the hours, so it leads to multiple data values for each date.
Solved by converting `POSIXct` to `POSIXlt` and adding the hour to the `POSIXlt` object. However another issue arises: the figure plots a 'jump' for saturdays and sundays (which are not present in the dataset).
[image]
How can I tell `plot` or `axis.POSIXct` not to create the lines which connect fridays values to mondays values?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Maybe the problem is that you are only using `as.Date()` on the axis call and not the plot class itself. Hard to say without seeing the data.

Comment: sample posted.. however, it seems I've found the error: I've defined the dates as `POSIXct` without specifying the hours, which are stored in a separate column... this lead to an error, because I have 24 posixct dates which are considered as the same date (no hour is provided).  I've tried to convert to `POSIXlt` using `as.POSIXlt` and adding hours with `$hour` but I'm not able to re-store the posixlt dates in the dataframe...